# Unable to solve error "reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference. vb.net "

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code

```
Case "Formula_MDX"
    Dim cubeid As String = Request("intCubeId")
    Dim strDimCode As String = Request("strDimCode")
    Dim strMdxFormula As String = Request("strMdxFormula")
    Dim result As String
    result =  HostAnalytics.HostAnalyzer.HostAnalyzer.setSubstituteVarMDXType(cubeid, strDimCode, strMdxFormula)

Case Else
Response.Write("Invalid call")
End Select
```

that vb method returns data of type string.
I declared the result of the typed string. but it is showing on that vb method like

> "reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference"

How to solve this? Did I make any other mistakes in this code?

Comment: Without knowing what the HostAnalytics namespace looks like, I'd say you're calling an instance method.  Try something like: `Dim ha As New HostAnalytics.HostAnalyzer.HostAnalyzer()` `result = ha.setSubstituteVarMDXType(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an object of that type, and invoke the method on that

```
Dim ha As New HostAnalytics.HostAnalyzer.HostAnalyzer()  'Edit, need New
result = ha.setSubstituteVarMDXType(cubeid, strDimCode, strMdxFormula)
```

Comment: @Jonsca.. but in second line it is showing "ha is used before it has been assigned a value"... what to do..!

Comment: have to initialize ha with new key word, such as     dim ha = new HostAnalytics.HostAnalyzer.HostAnalyzer